# Activity won't start and initilazing Array Adapter syntax doesn't work

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-arrayadapter

I'm working on an app in Kotlin using ListViews and ArrayAdapters, this is the code that I've written and it seems like it's outdated code. Maybe there's an alternative to ArrayAdapters but I don't know any alternatives

```
class ListFrag : ListFragment() {

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list2, container, false)
    }

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
    }

    override fun onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState)
        val data = arrayOf("1. Text", "2. Text", "3.Text");

        val itemsAdapter : ArrayAdapter<String> = ArrayAdapter(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
        this.listAdapter = itemsAdapter;
    }

    override fun onListItemClick(l: ListView, v: View, position: Int, id: Long) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id)
    }

}
```

This is the error message I get when I run the program

```
 Process: com.example.fragments2, PID: 15030
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.fragments2/com.example.fragments2.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #10: Error inflating class fragment
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
        at androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:370)
        at androidx.fragment.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:151)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.ensureInflatedFragmentView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1144)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:851)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1133)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addFragment(FragmentManagerImpl.java:1393)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManagerImpl.java:3205)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.onCreateView(FragmentController.java:134)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.dispatchFragmentsOnCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:357)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:336)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:777)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.fragments2.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.kt:10)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

Your LogCat response is telling you whats wrong with your code. Follow as it says this issue will be fixed.

Comment: Well it might(that is why I said "this issue will be fixed") but there would be another issue that is causing that. Check your LogCat stacktrace and fix that.

Comment: Post the XML after you have added that fix and stacktrace too